# PHP Export to CSV does not send all data to the file

Tags: php, sql-server, csv

I am exporting to CSV from my php reporting website. I have reports that are more than 80k rows. When I export one of them the whole data set does not get exported. I have tried several times with a report that is 88k+ rows and it exports 87k+ rows and then stops part way through the last row that is exported.

What is going on? The query that pulls the data from MSSQL is correct (I've checked).

Here's my Export file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('DBConn.php');
include 'Helper/LogReport.php';
if(isset($_GET['Id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['Id'];
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT QName, tsql from pmdb.QDefs WHERE Id = ' . $id);
    $query->execute();
    $qdef = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
else
{        
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT QName, tsql from pmdb.QDefs WHERE QName = '" .$TableName. "'");
    $query->execute();
    $qdef = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}


// Create and open file for writing
$filepath = 'exports/';
$filename = $qdef['QName'] . '.csv';
try
{
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset:UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Something went wrong<br>";
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage()));
}

//define separators
$sep = ",";     //separator
$br = "\r\n";   //line break

// Use returned tsql field as query for dataset
$tsql = $qdef['tsql'];
if(isset($DataReturn))
{
    if(strpos($DataReturn['Order'],'EDIT'))
    {
        $DataReturn['Order'] = str_replace('EDIT','Id',$DataReturn['Order']);
    }
    $tsql = $tsql . $DataReturn['WhereClause'] . $DataReturn['Order'] . $DataReturn['Limit'];
}
$query = $conn->prepare($tsql);
$query->execute();

// Output data to CSV file
$headers = NULL;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //Write column headings to file
    if (is_null($headers))
    {
        $headers = array_keys($row);
        if ($headers[0] == 'ID')
            $headers[0] = 'Id';
        foreach($headers as $Header)
        {
            echo $Header. ",";
        }
        echo $br;
    }
    //Write data
    $modRow = preg_replace('/ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}/', '', $row);
    $modRow = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $modRow );

    foreach($modRow as $RowPrint)
    {
        echo '"' .trim(unserialize(serialize($RowPrint))). '"' .$sep;
    }
    echo $br;
}
```

I don't see anything that would stop the data stream from completing the export.

**EDIT**

I have tried the `fputcsv()` method like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('DBConn.php');
include 'Helper/LogReport.php';
//print_r($_GET);
if(isset($_GET['Id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['Id'];
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT QName, tsql from pmdb.QDefs WHERE Id = ' . $id);
    $query->execute();
    $qdef = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
else
{        
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT QName, tsql from pmdb.QDefs WHERE QName = '" .$TableName. "'");
    $query->execute();
    $qdef = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}


// Create and open file for writing
$filepath = 'exports/';
$filename = $qdef['QName'] . '.csv';
try
{
    $openFile = fopen($filepath . $filename,'a');
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset:UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Something went wrong<br>";
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage()));
}

//define separators
$sep = ",";     //separator
$br = "\r\n";   //line break

// Use returned tsql field as query for dataset
$tsql = $qdef['tsql'];
if(isset($DataReturn))
{
    if(strpos($DataReturn['Order'],'EDIT'))
    {
        $DataReturn['Order'] = str_replace('EDIT','Id',$DataReturn['Order']);
    }
    $tsql = $tsql . $DataReturn['WhereClause'] . $DataReturn['Order'] . $DataReturn['Limit'];
}
$query = $conn->prepare($tsql);
$query->execute();

// Output data to CSV file
$headers = NULL;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //Write column headings to file
    if (is_null($headers))
    {
        $headers = array_keys($row);
        if ($headers[0] == 'ID')
            $headers[0] = 'Id';
        fputcsv($openFile, $headers);
    }
    //Write data
    $modRow = preg_replace('/ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}/', '', $row);
    $modRow = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $modRow );

    fputcsv($openFile, $modRow, ',','"');//print_r($modRow);
    foreach($modRow as $RowPrint)
    {
        error_log(date("Y/m/d h:i:sa "). ' RowPrint: ' .$RowPrint. '\n',3,'C:\Temp\LogPHP.txt');
    }
    echo $br;
}

// Close file
fclose($openFile);
```

This just creates an empty file.

**UPDATE**

I ran a couple of reports for one that should have 103k+ rows. They both stopped between 61000 and 62000 rows. I did a character count and they both have around 40 million. I don't see anything about a 40million character limit.

Comment: Maybe the php allowed execution time? You get no error/warnings?

Comment: Maybe you are blowing one of these EXCEL limits https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Why can't you use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: By the way, there is not much point in preparing sql statements if you are going to inject the variables directly anyway.

Comment: @MarkBaker I have tried the fputcsv(), but nothing ever gets exported when I do. It's what I originally tried. I think that because some of the data has `'` and `"` and seems to mess things up. And I'm not allowed to remove or change them.

Comment: @RiggsFolly After looking at the link you provided I don't see any limit that I'm exceeding. Selecting all the data in the sheet the count is 3044832 well below the 2billion limit.

Comment: If you write the data to a file rather than echoing it directly back to the browser, do you get all the rows written?

Comment: `I think that because some of the data has ' and " and seems to mess things up`... well your code does nothing to prevent the file getting messed up if data contains `'` or `"` (or `,`).... but fputcsv() does ensure that it's correctly handled. [Your code fails completely](https://3v4l.org/i3v02)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Other than the `fputcsv()` (which I can't get to work for me) I don't know of any other way to export the data directly to a file. The `echo` works except that I don't get all the data. Can you point me to an example of another way?

Comment: Well just write it out as a line in a file. Then count the lines, then you will know if all are written or not

Comment: @MarkBaker I will attempt the `fputcsv()` again to see if I can get it to work. I am only guessing at what the problem with it is, I don't know that it was the `'` and `"`

Comment: @jeroen That is a good point. I'll have to update my code. Though all that I'm injecting is my code not from a user's input so at least it's safe unless I messed up something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working and figured out how to get the `fputcsv` to work.

I needed to add an `exit()` to the end of the export. Now it not only sends all the data `fputcsv` works as well. I got the answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299078/why-wont-my-fputcsv-work) that I ask about getting `fputcsv` to work.