# Why won't my fputcsv work?

Tags: php, arrays, fputcsv

I cannot get the PHP built-in function `fputcsv()` to work. Here is what I've tried:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include('DBConn.php');              //My SQL server connection information
include 'Helper/LogReport.php';     //Keeps a count of how many times reports are exported


$query = $conn->query("SELECT QName, tsql from pmdb.QDefs WHERE QName = '" .$TableName. "'");
$query->execute();
$qdef = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


// Create and open file for writing
$filepath = 'exports/';
$filename = $qdef['QName'] . '.csv';
try
{
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset:UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    //$openFile = fopen('php://output','w');
    $openFile = fopen($filepath . $filename,'w');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Something went wrong<br>";
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage()));
}

//define separators
$sep = ",";     //separator
$br = "\r\n";   //line break

// Use returned tsql field as query for dataset
$tsql = $qdef['tsql'];
if(isset($DataReturn))
{
    if(strpos($DataReturn['Order'],'EDIT'))
    {
        $DataReturn['Order'] = str_replace('EDIT','Id',$DataReturn['Order']);
    }
    $tsql = $tsql . $DataReturn['WhereClause'] . $DataReturn['Order'] . $DataReturn['Limit'];
}

$query = $conn->query($tsql);
$query->execute();

// Output data to CSV file
$headers = NULL;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //Write column headings to file
    if (is_null($headers))
    {
        $headers = array_keys((array)$row);
        if ($headers[0] == 'ID')
            $headers[0] = 'Id';
        fputcsv($openFile, $headers, ',','"');

    }
    //Write data
    $modRow = preg_replace('/ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}/', '', array_values($row));
    $modRow = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $modRow );
    /*
    $modRow = str_replace('\r\n', " ", $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace('\n\r', " ", $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace('\n', " ", $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace('\r', " ", $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace(' ', " ", $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace('Â ', " ", $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace('"', '', $modRow);
    $modRow = str_replace("'", "", $modRow);
    */
    fputcsv($openFile, $modRow, ',','"');
}

// Close file
fclose($openFile);
```

But nothing gets printed to the file, it's just blank. Am I setting something up wrong?

**EDIT**

I have tried every variation for the `fopen` that I could find on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), but they all give me a blank file when using `fputcsv`. I only get data in the file when I `echo` the arrays.

**END OF EDIT**

You can see the header array is setup from the array keys returned from the query to the DB. I can `echo` them and get the correct headers.

Then there are the rows of data themselves. I remove unwanted characters, but they are still arrays of data and should print with the `fputcsv`. Again I can `echo` the contents of the array by looping through it. That's how I've been getting the exports to work right now, but I know that is just a workaround and want to get the `fputcsv` working.

This is how I'm getting the rows printed:

```
foreach($modRow as $RowPrint)
{
    echo '"' .trim(unserialize(serialize($RowPrint))). '"' .$sep;
}
echo $br;
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the output when I `print_r` the headers:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Id
    [1] => QSRC
    [2] => QNAME
    [3] => QDEF
    [4] => ISACTIVE
    [5] => RUNREPORT
    [6] => FILEPATH
    [7] => TSQL
)
```

and here's one line from when I `print_r` the `$modRow`:

```
Array
(
    [Id] => 60
    [QSRC] => bau
    [QNAME] => Oops I deleted this!
    [QDEF] => SELECT REGION
    [ISACTIVE] => 0
    [RUNREPORT] => 0
    [FILEPATH] => 
    [TSQL] => 
)
```

I `print_r` both after the `fputcsv` should have printed them into the file. These are the only things in the file.

Comment: What does your http servers error log file show?

Comment: @arkascha I don't know. I can't find it on the server, though I'm not sure where to look either. I've checked in the same directory that the website is, but it's not there. I've also checked in every folder that has `Log` in the name that I've been able to find.

Comment: Do the headers print in the csv? Also $modRow is not a string. Its an object

Comment: @jeroen I do have a valid file to write to. I am able to `echo` the contents to the file I just can't get the `fputcsv` to work. I followed advice from http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php there is one comment that mentions the binary update mode that is the `+b` on the end.

Comment: @chris85 `$modRow` is not a string. It's an array created from `$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and then updated to remove unwanted characters.

Comment: You see, the issue with not looking into your error log file is exactly what we see her. Instead of using that information there is a huge guessing game on the way. That makes zero sense. You _cannot_ develop or operate a web site without monitoring the http servers error log file.

Comment: <?php
  $errorPath = ini_get('error_log');
?>

Comment: @arkascha The last errors from either server are from yesterday and the day before. I've attempted several times to use `fputcsv` this morning, but there are no entries from today on either server.

Comment: You can hardcode the path and array of fputcsv to figure out if its the path or the array. Delete the file, so you can see if really a new one will appear.

Comment: @Mike add an `exit();` at the end. And change back to using the `$openFile = fopen('php://output', 'w');` for $openFile

Comment: @CodyBrown That did it! Adding `exit()`! Put that as an answer and I'll close this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed my first answer, as it was incorrect.

*******************EDIT*******************

You need to add this to the end of your file:

```
exit();
```

This tells the browser you are finished writing to the file and ensures no extra content is sent to the browser for security reasons.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Been fighting this for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use php://stdout to send output to the browser. You could use php://memory instead to store the string and then read it back.

```
$fd = fopen('php://memory','rw');
fwrite($fd, 'hey there'); //This would be your fputcsv stuff
fseek($fd, 0); //Reset the file pointer
$content = fread($fd, 4096); //This will read 4096 bytes maximum
echo $content;
```

Comment: I don't want anything sent to the browser, I want a file exported to CSV.

Comment: Ok, you sending headers out made me think that. You don't need them then. The other thing I see then is that you're writing to stdout, not the file. And you want to use 'wr' flags or similar, not 'a+b'

Comment: The writing to stdout was a mistake I made in the copy and paste. I have fixed that in the code above. I have also updated my code (including what's in the question) to show that I'm now writing to a file that was opened with the `w` flag.

Comment: If I remove those three `header` lines then all that happens when I click the Export button is I get a blank screen, no file or anything.